# How to call an async function and block all other coroutines until it's finished?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a discord bot, and in its `on_connect` function, I loop through and check the bot's MongoDB database (eg check for new guilds that joined while it's down). That piece of code looks like this:

```py
# inside the client class
async def on_connect(self):
    await self.init_database()  # I need this to block everything

    # ...

async def init_database(self):
    # loop through everything in the db with a custom data manager that uses Motor to connect
    # with MongoDB (requires async/await).
    # takes ~1 minute to run if I don't block other coroutines.
```

Is there any way I can block all other coroutines until `init_database` finished running?

Edit: I just realized that, if I don't make all of the coroutines inside of `init_database` blocking, only making `init_database` blocking would be useless. It would be best if I can make all coros in a coro blocking, otherwise I would have to use both PyMongo and Motor.

Comment: I am async noob, I may be wrong, but `init_database` doesn't have to be async? Async functions can call non-async functions, and as long as it does not yield (give back control), then it will block other coroutines, cos it's not like threads.

Comment: @JamesLin Inside `init_database`, I use Motor to update the database, which uses async and await.